# Como obtenho um Surface para executar um vídeo utilizando o ExoPlayer?

Tags: android

Preciso executar vídeo em minha aplicação Android utilizando o ExoPlayer, um projeto da google que permite DASH, cache persistente. [**Página Oficial do Projeto aqui**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html)

Porém, o método `exoPlayer.sendMessage` tem um parâmetro da classe `Surface`, mas não consegui encontrar esse tipo de View, então Utilizei `VideoSurfaceView`, mas não funcionou. Segue código e LogCat.

**LogCat**:

```
05-07 21:30:10.438    7616-7630/com.promobile.vod.vodmobile E/ExoPlayerImplInternal﹕ Internal runtime error.
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.exoplayer.VideoSurfaceView cannot be cast to android.view.Surface
        at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.handleMessage(MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.java:331)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.sendMessageInternal(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:540)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:219)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(PriorityHandlerThread.java:40)
```

Código **MainActivity.java**

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setParameters();

    builderExoPlayer();
}

private void setParameters() {
    videoSurfaceView = (VideoSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
}

private void builderExoPlayer() {
    int numRenderers = 2;
    Uri URI = Uri.parse("http://www.semanticdevlab.com/abc.mp4");

    SampleSource sampleSource = new DefaultSampleSource(new FrameworkSampleExtractor(getApplicationContext(), URI, null), numRenderers);

    TrackRenderer videoTrackRenderer = new MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer(sampleSource, MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT);
    TrackRenderer audioTrackRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource);

    ExoPlayer exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(numRenderers);

    exoPlayer.prepare(videoTrackRenderer, audioTrackRenderer);

    exoPlayer.sendMessage(videoTrackRenderer, MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE, videoSurfaceView);

    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
}
```

código **activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.google.android.exoplayer.VideoSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surface"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Como eu obtenho esse Surface para executar o ExoPlayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente obter `Surface` como é feito no aplicativo de demonstração da página oficial que você citou:

```
exoPlayer.sendMessage(videoTrackRenderer, MediaCodecVideoTrackRenderer.MSG_SET_SURFACE,
         videoSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
```

Note que, de acordo com a documentação de [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html), o objeto `SurfaceHolder` retornado por `getHolder()` pode não estar disponível imediatamente; pode ser necessário implementar os callbacks `surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder)` e `surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder)`.

Comment: Perdão, houve um erro no nome da variável `surfaceView`, ela é do tipo `VideoSurfaceView`.

Comment: Alterei minha resposta.

Comment: Perfeito! Eu estava verificando aqui a documentação e é exatamente isso! Obrigado pela explicação detalhada!